# After copying my project folder. File uploading doesn't work. But the older one does

Tags: php, laravel

After copying my project folder. File uploading doesn't work. But the older one is working. I did:
composer install
composer update
php artisan clear:cache

Comment: Want to post the error you get when trying to upload a file?

Comment: Its working now. I run php artisan storage:link. it seems i need to do this everytime of copying the project folder into another path

Comment: You could also jut upload into the public_folder().